# SmartJobBoard 4.2 help understanding pattern

Tags: php, frameworks

I am new to SJB, and i want to make some correction in backend of this CMS, but its a little bit mess. I've understood  there is a table in database with is called pages and when i make new record in table with different URI - new page is created.

But I want to add my custom view into that page, for now when i create  page like that only layout loads without view. In system i have user folder with contains all `.tpl` but I couldn't load some of them into that page. I saw and some folder module - column and folder modules, also function - column and folder functions, but they are still not loading.

Please help me understand this framework if u had expirience with SmartJobBoard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an admin when you create a new page this creates a row in table `Pages`. By default it is created with no template and with module:static_content and function:show_static_content which by default just displays the content.

In order to update the template update the static_content.tpl under appearance -> Edit templates
/admin/edit-templates/?module_name=static_content&template_name=static_content.tpl

The templates you are seeing in the system/users folder are the ones used for registration/editing profile/etc

Comment: Can you tell me how to make new function in Module -> users. I've made rating system and now i want to make one page with statistics about this but i don't know how to make new function and when i user edit_profile function or smth else - makes another page not mine.

Comment: Add a new page in the pages table and also In the file /src/system/modules/users/config.php add a new function just like other functions, now create a new script ex: statistics.php and also add new template /src/templates/_system/admin/users/statistics.tpl

Answer (score 0):

The steps for creating a custom template file and PHP script in a smart job board are :

1. Create a row in the pages table in DB.
2. Register your script and other info in the related module in the config file (Path:/public_html/system/modules).
3. last step to register your class in /public_html/system/core/.classmapcache.php this is a hidden file